# Tag synonym suggestion: multiple-comparisons <-> multiple-hypothesis

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The terms [multiple-comparisons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-comparisons) and [multiple-hypothesis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-hypothesis) are used interchangeably.

Comment: If nobody disagree with that, I will apply the suggested tag update. I don't know how and why the `multiple-hypothesis` tag once has been created but it is certainly misused from what I've seen.

Comment: As this suggestion has been implemented long ago, consider accepting chl's answer to make this thread visually appear as "resolved". Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Task completed: new questions should see their `multiple-hypothesis` tag remapped to `multiple-comparisons`.